# Создание временной переменной в Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Я только начал изучать Thymeleaf и мне требуется передать в form определённую ссылку. Нашел код для jstl

```
<c:if test="${empty film.title}">
    <c:url value="/add" var="var"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!empty film.title}">
    <c:url value="/edit" var="var"/>
</c:if>
```

Как такое сделать в Thymeleaf, чтоб потом подставить в th:action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы воспользовался ответом @OlegMarchenko и не стал бы создавать временную переменную, если конечно вы не собираетесь использовать её несколько раз. А то что вы спрашиваете в вашем вопросе выглядит примерно так ...

```
<form th:with="actionUrl=${empty film.title} ? @{'/add'} : @{'/edit'}" th:action="${actionUrl}"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать сделать так:

```
<form method="..." th:action="${empty film.title} ? __@{/add}__ : __@{/edit}__"></form>
```